# How can I make an immovable HTML header?

Tags: html

On iPads and iPhones, the top of a website can be moved, revealing a white background. Some websites like stackoverflow.com have an immovable header. How can I replicate this?

Comment: Do you mean just a simple fixed header, or a header that starts to scroll up out of view, and then slides down and stays in place when you are scrolling?

Comment: I just want a simple fixed header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class `fixed-to-top` on the header element that you want to fix

Now add following to css

```
 .fixed-to-top{
     Position:fixed; 
     Top:0; //optional as this is set by default 
  }
```

`position : fixed` fixiates the element on top by default even on scrolling.

Comment: You're assuming 'header' is the element being used here... This code might never have worked, so your answer could really do with some more to it, as you haven't explained your answer at all.

Comment: Yes but there is no indication to what element or class to fix the position